# oracle: How to get the latest changed record matching conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a source table with the following columns(among other things), NONE of these are unique identifiers and I don't have rights to correct what I see as a mistake. also, the data is in such a state that makes this non-trivial.

id (again, not unique)
is_current (as opposed to historical)
code
last_update_date

What i need to find is a list of each id and the associated code for the row that is_current with the most recent last_update_date for each list.

I'm thinking I need to use some kind of select over partition but that is a bit out of my league.
here's my initial try:

```
select id, 
  max(code) keep (dense_rank last order by last_upd_date)
                        over (partition by id)
  from table
  WHERE is_current='CURRENT' and ORG='E';
```

Sample data: (sorry it's not formatting)

```
id | is_current | code | last_upd_date      | org |
---+------------+------+--------------------+-----+
1  | CURRENT    | ABCD | 12-JUL-13 10:32:29 |  E  |
1  | CURRENT    | EFGH | 13-JUL-13 10:32:29 |  E  |
2  | CURRENT    | ABCD | 12-JUL-13 10:32:29 |  E  |
3  | CURRENT    | ABCD | 13-JUL-13 10:32:29 |  E  |
3  | CURRENT    | EFGH | 12-JUL-13 10:32:29 |  E  |
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In your query, the MAX analytic function will give you a result *for every row returned* by the WHERE clause so you'll see identical rows where the IDs are the same. Throw on a SELECT **DISTINCT** ... and you'll get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select id, code
  from (select id,
               code,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by id 
                     order by last_upd_date desc) as rn
          from tbl
         where is_current = 'CURRENT'
           and org = 'E')
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. also, thanks for fixing the formatting on the question somehow.